# Copying the Auth key for a Firebase powered app to another phone?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

App A does not allow the user to log in 2 devices simultaneously.

App A is on phone A which uses Firebase authentication to keep a user logged in persistently. 
Is there a way to transfer the Auth state file to phone B, so that the user shows as logged in when app A is opened on phone B?

Phone B is rooted.

Comment: How exactly does App A prevent sign-ins from multiple devices?  That's not something Firebase Auth can force as a limitation.  It's designed to let anyone with credentials sign in from anywhere.

Comment: @DougStevenson I mean sigining into device B while staying logged into device A. Both running simultaneously.

Comment: What's the problem with that?  You don't have to do anything special to sign in and stay signed in with multiple devices.  Why do you need to transfer auth state when you can just sign in again normally?

Comment: @DougStevenson  I'm trying to run this specific app on an emulator. But the problem is the app blocks authentication and login from emulator. So I'm wondering if there is anyway to transfer the login state from the device B to device A. I'm assuming firebase is storing the persistent state in some file that maybe I can find?

Comment: All Android apps are required to use the same local storage space designated to them by the OS.

Comment: @DougStevenson so it is not possible to transfer the storage to the other device so the app thinks its authenticated?

Comment: I don't know.  Find the local storage for the app and give it a try.

Comment: That's why I was trying to figure out what path Firebase uses and if i need root to access it. i haven't figured it out yetwill post back if I find it